# excel 2010 application sendkeys ctrl with F1

Tags: excel, sendkeys, vba

According to the documentation I have, this expression:

```
application.sendkeys("^{F1}")
```

and this expression

```
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
```

should both minimize the ribbon bar.

The commandbars expression works
but, the `application.sendkeys` expression only displays the help screen.

Is my syntax wrong or does application.sendkeys just not work when using the caret in conjunction with function keys?

Comment: Were you in the IDE when you ran the `application.sendkeys("^{F1}")`?  If so, you were sending the keys to the IDE, not to Excel.  (SendKeys just sends keystrokes to the currently active application - not specifically to Excel itself - which is why it is very problematic using SendKeys unless you can ensure that the user is kept at least 10 metres away from the computer while the macro is running.)

Comment: did you mean to use `Application.OnKey`?

Comment: YowE3K is right. Your expression runs as anticipated when it is evoked from excel itself (instead of from the VBA window).  A good reason to avoid SendKeys.